# New tag suggestion - OSINT

Tags: discussion, tags

I find it curious that there aren't any tags for open source intelligence (OSINT) or even threat intelligence (TI). There do seem to be multiple questions that could make use of an `OSINT` tag, including:

- [What is OSINT (open source intelligence)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118524/what-is-osint-open-source-intelligence)
- [PTES: Differences between Internet Footprint, OSINT and footprinting](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87137/ptes-differences-between-internet-footprint-osint-and-footprinting)
- [How do I investigate where personal information in a fraudulent email was leaked from?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159600/how-do-i-investigate-where-personal-information-in-a-fraudulent-email-was-leaked/159612#159612)

Is that something that could be added/created? Does anyone have a better suggestion for the tag name (i.e. `open-source-intelligence`)?

Comment: No opinion on if the tags are needed or not, but I would stongly recommend that it is written out and not abbreviated if one is created. Makes less room for misunterstanding.

Comment: @Anders Good point. I wasn't sure if the `open-source-intelligence` tag length balanced out against the common knowledge level of `OSINT` but you're right, it does make for less ambiguity.

Comment: In my opinion, the acronym OSINT in a security context is fairly common and I rarely see it spelled out. But I'm happy to be overruled.

Comment: I would prefer `OSINT` rather than `open-source-intelligence`